# Solr virtual or test environment

Tags: solr, solrj

Does Solr have support for setting up a virtual environment for testing? I'm writing some test cases of a SolrJ client, using an `EmbeddedSolrServer`.

Right now I'm looking at having my JUnit test case generate a temporary Solr home that can be passed to the CoreContainer used by `EmbeddedSolrServer`. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look on class - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-test-framework/org/apache/solr/SolrTestCaseJ4.html

All you need is to extend this class, and in test method you could access Solr, send queries, assert response, etc.

Just an example of this kind of test from Solr repo - https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/c3ef419e4fb720866e88e0020b182de3e25a4fbb/solr/core/src/test/org/apache/solr/search/TestFieldSortValues.java

Comment: Thanks, Mysterion! Just what I needed.